# Error al cargar Datatable por problemas de tildes

Tags: php, datatables

Buen día, tengo un Datatable que funciona correctamente pero en el momento de cargar algún registro que tenga ñ o caracteres especiales me aparece un error, he intentado solucionar el problema pero no he podido, he intentado agregar compatibilidad de caracteres pero me sigue apareciendo el error y mi Datatable no carga, si alguien me pudiera colaborar se lo agradeciera, he intentado todo lo que he podido pero aun no encuentro la solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

envio mi modelo y conexión:

**productos.modelo.php:**

```
static public function mdlMostrarProductos($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY id DESC");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;


    }
```

**conexion.php:**

```
<?php

class Conexion{

    public function conectar(){

        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cone_fajas",
                        "cone_fajas",
                        "Cone=0000",
                        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
                        );

        return $link;

    }

}
```

**productos.controlador.php:**

```
    /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "productos";

        $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;
    
    }
```

**tablaproductos.ajax.php:**

```
class TablaProductos{

  /*=============================================
  MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
  =============================================*/ 

  public function mostrarTablaProductos(){  

    $item = null;
    $valor = null;

    $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor);

    $datosJson = '

        {   
            "data":[';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($productos); $i++){
            
            

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS CATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item = "id";
            $valor = $productos[$i]["id_categoria"];

            $categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

            if($categorias["categoria"] == ""){

                $categoria = "SIN CATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $categoria = $categorias["categoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS SUBCATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item2 = "id";
            $valor2 = $productos[$i]["id_subcategoria"];

            $subcategorias = ControladorSubCategorias::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item2, $valor2);

            if($subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"] == ""){

                $subcategoria = "SIN SUBCATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $subcategoria = $subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            AGREGAR ETIQUETAS DE ESTADO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["estado"] == 0){

                $colorEstado = "btn-danger";
                $textoEstado = "Desactivado";
                $estadoProducto = 1;

            }else{

                $colorEstado = "btn-success";
                $textoEstado = "Activado";
                $estadoProducto = 0;

            }

            $estado = "<button class='btn btn-xs btnActivar ".$colorEstado."' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' estadoProducto='".$estadoProducto."'>".$textoEstado."</button>";

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS CABECERAS
            =============================================*/

            $item3 = "ruta";
            $valor3 = $productos[$i]["ruta"];

            $cabeceras = ControladorCabeceras::ctrMostrarCabeceras($item3, $valor3);

            if($cabeceras["portada"] != ""){

                $imagenPortada = "<img src='".$cabeceras["portada"]."' class='img-thumbnail imgPortadaProductos' width='100px'>";

            }else{

                $imagenPortada = "<img src='vistas/img/cabeceras/default/default.jpg' class='img-thumbnail imgPortadaProductos' width='100px'>";
            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER IMAGEN PRINCIPAL
            =============================================*/

            $imagenPrincipal = "<img src='".$productos[$i]["portada"]."' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaPrincipal' width='100px'>";

            /*=============================================
            TRAER MULTIMEDIA
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["multimedia"] != null){

                $multimedia = json_decode($productos[$i]["multimedia"],true);

                if($multimedia[0]["foto"] != ""){

                    $vistaMultimedia = "<img src='".$multimedia[0]["foto"]."' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaMultimedia' width='100px'>";

                }else{

                    $vistaMultimedia = "<img src='http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/".$productos[$i]["multimedia"]."/hqdefault.jpg' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaMultimedia' width='100px'>";

                }


            }else{

                $vistaMultimedia = "<img src='vistas/img/multimedia/default/default.jpg' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaMultimedia' width='100px'>";

            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER DETALLES
            =============================================*/

            $detalles = json_decode($productos[$i]["detalles"],true);

            if($productos[$i]["tipo"] == "fisico"){

                $talla = json_encode($detalles["Talla"]);
                $color = json_encode($detalles["Color"]);
                $marca = json_encode($detalles["Marca"]);

                $vistaDetalles = "Talla: ".str_replace(array("[","]",'"'), "", $talla)." - Color: ".str_replace(array("[","]",'"'), "", $color)." - Marca: ".str_replace(array("[","]",'"'), "", $marca);


            }else{


                $vistaDetalles = "Clases: ".$detalles["Clases"].", Tiempo: ".$detalles["Tiempo"].", Nivel: ".$detalles["Nivel"].", Acceso: ".$detalles["Acceso"].", Dispositivo: ".$detalles["Dispositivo"].", Certificado: ".$detalles["Certificado"];

            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER PRECIO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["precio"] == 0){

                $precio = "Gratis";
            
            }else{

                $precio = "$ ".number_format($productos[$i]["precio"],2);

            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER ENTREGA
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["entrega"] == 0){

                $entrega = "Inmediata";
            
            }else{

                $entrega = $productos[$i]["entrega"]. " días hábiles";

            }

            /*=============================================
            REVISAR SI HAY OFERTAS
            =============================================*/
            
            if($productos[$i]["oferta"] != 0){

                if($productos[$i]["precioOferta"] != 0){    

                    $tipoOferta = "PRECIO";
                    $valorOferta = "$ ".number_format($productos[$i]["precioOferta"],2);

                }else{

                    $tipoOferta = "DESCUENTO";
                    $valorOferta = $productos[$i]["descuentoOferta"]." %";  

                }   

            }else{

                $tipoOferta = "No tiene oferta";
                $valorOferta = 0;
                
            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER IMAGEN OFERTA
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["imgOferta"] != ""){

                $imgOferta = "<img src='".$productos[$i]["imgOferta"]."' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaProductos' width='100px'>";

            }else{

                $imgOferta = "<img src='vistas/img/ofertas/default/default.jpg' class='img-thumbnail imgTablaProductos' width='100px'>";

            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS ACCIONES
            =============================================*/

            $acciones = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarProducto'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' imgOferta='".$productos[$i]["imgOferta"]."' rutaCabecera='".$productos[$i]["ruta"]."' imgPortada='".$cabeceras["portada"]."' imgPrincipal='".$productos[$i]["portada"]."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";

            /*=============================================
            CONSTRUIR LOS DATOS JSON
            =============================================*/


            $datosJson .='[
                    
                    "'.($i+1).'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["titulo"].'",
                    "'.$categoria.'",
                    "'.$subcategoria.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["ruta"].'",
                    "'.$estado.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["tipo"].'",
                    "'.$cabeceras["descripcion"].'",
                    "'.$cabeceras["palabrasClaves"].'",
                    "'.$imagenPortada.'",
                    "'.$imagenPrincipal.'",
                    "'.$vistaMultimedia.'",
                    "'.$vistaDetalles.'",
                    "'.$precio.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["peso"].' kg",
                    "'.$entrega.'",
                    "'.$tipoOferta.'",
                    "'.$valorOferta.'",
                    "'.$imgOferta.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["finOferta"].'",          
                    "'.$acciones.'"    

            ],';

        }

        $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

        $datosJson .= ']

        }';

        echo $datosJson;
  }


}
```

Comment: me puedes dar un ejemplo por que no se exactamente donde debo colocar utf8_encode($variable)

Comment: Y en estos casos no se puede usar la **ssp.class** ???

Comment: Suena más a problema de donde traes la información, en mi caso me marcaba el mismo error, pero no era por tildes o acentos o ñ, era por que no estaba bien el JSON, pero dale revisa las respuestas que te dejaron

Answer (score 0):

Si esperas un Json como respuesta, podrías tratar de hacer el return con la función **json_encode** : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
  /*=============================================
    MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
    =============================================*/

    static public function ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "productos";

        $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return json_encode($respuesta);
    
    }
```

Comment: aagregando json_encode como lo agrego solo me muestra un registro de la tabla y lo muestra incompleto.

Comment: tambien agregue el ajax en la pregunta de la datatable

Comment: ¿Puede ser que la función ctrMostrarProductos devuelve solo un registro de la tabla?
¿Ya verificaste la salida de esa función? @Giovanny

Answer (score 0):

A las variables que contengan tildes o cualquier caracter latino, pásale la función `utf8_encode($variable)`. Por ejemplo, en **tablaproductos.ajax.php**, en el momento en que empiezas a iterar los datos dentro del ciclo...

```
$categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);
if($categorias["categoria"] == ""){
    $categoria = utf8_encode("SIN CATEGORÍA");
}else{
    $categoria = utf8_encode($categorias["categoria"]);
}
```

Esto lo debes hacer en todas las variables que contengan texto con caracteres latinos como tildes o ñ. No es necesario para los valores numéricos por obvias razones.

Comment: La función `utf8_encode` fue deprecada en versiones recientes de PHP, por la cual no es recomendable su uso https://php.watch/versions/8.2/utf8_encode-utf8_decode-deprecated

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Gracias por tu observación. Tienes razón, a partir de la versión 8.2 específicamente deprecaron la función. Dejemos la respuesta temporalmente, al menos hasta que el OP nos confirme si puede o no usar la función dependiendo de su versión de `php` o si la respuesta soluciona su problema. En caso de que no se cumplan estas condiciones, me comprometo a eliminar la respuesta.